# How to list all documents the user can read from a Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How do you get all documents in a collection, for which the current user has read permissions?

Trying to get *all* documents results in a permissions error, because it includes attempts to read documents where the user does not have permission (rather than returning the filtered list of documents).

Each user in this app can belong to multiple groups. Reads are locked down to the groups that they have been added to.

```
match groups/{group} {
  allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(group)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

Here's how this would look with a hypothetical `subcollection-contains-id` operator.

```
firestore()
  .collection("groups")
  .where("users", "subcollection-contains-id", user.uid);
```

As a temporary workaround I've moved this logic to a cloud function. Here's a shorthand of how it works.

```
for (let group of firestore().collection("groups")) {
  let user = firestore.doc(`groups/${group.id}/users/${uid}`);

  if (user.exists) {
    // Send this group id to the client
  }
}
```

How can I keep these concerns together and move this logic to the client side without relaxing the security rules?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `owners` field in the documents inside a collection

`owners: ["uid1", "uid2"]`

Then, you could get all the posts with uid by searching with `array_contains`

`ref.where("owners", "array-contains", uid)`

In rules, you could add sth like these:

`allow read: if request.resource.data.owners.hasAny([request.auth.uid]) == true`

`allow update: if request.resource.data.owners.hasAny([request.auth.uid]) == true`

Comment: I just checked again. It s still working. May i know which part doesn’t work? Any error code ?

Comment: I will need to report back to you another day as I had already opted for another route for my project. My original goal was to have database entry `path/doc_uid1` only where `user1` has access to this `doc_uid1` through the security rules that you suggested. When I did `db.collection("path").where("owners", "array-contains", uid).get()` I believe I got some permission denied error - but this is based off of my memory. Just to clarify, `db.collection("path").doc("doc_uid1").get()` is perfectly fine. It is as if `user1` does not have permission to *list* `path/`.

Comment: Sorry @hugomac I must admit defeat. It has worked for me now. Kudos to you! Maybe I made a typo before or something... Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: No worry. Happy coding ~

Comment: May I borrow your opinion for a follow up question? Right now in this set up, if `user1` and `user2` have access to the same document (i.e. this document has these two `owners`), when each individual user query this document they can see the full list of owners. Is there a way to structure the security rules or the database so that each user cannot see the full `owners` list? Is duplicating documents the only way?

Comment: You could create sub collection to store user specific data. For details, you may check the documentation of collection group queries of Firestore.